# How to build Python 3.11 on MacOSX (arm64) from sources?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, build, clang

I want to build Python 3.11 from sources on MacOSX (arm64).
I downloaded Python sources from the official website.
Installed all necessary libraries with Brew. Unpacked sources and configure with:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
```

Then: make -j2 and get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_libintl_bindtextdomain", referenced from:
      __locale_bindtextdomain in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_dcgettext", referenced from:
      __locale_dcgettext in _localemodule.o
      __locale_dcgettext_impl in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_dgettext", referenced from:
      __locale_dgettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_gettext", referenced from:
      __locale_gettext in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_setlocale", referenced from:
      __locale_setlocale in _localemodule.o
      __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
  "_libintl_textdomain", referenced from:
      __locale_textdomain in _localemodule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```